# I can't get connected to Jira using the Atlassian.SDK

Tags: c#, jira

I am trying to use the Atlassian.SDK in an Azure function project and it won't even connect.    This is jira cloud so I'm using https://mycompany.atlassian.net as the URL. The one thing that wasn't clear in the docs was if you need the entire API endpoint or just the FQDN as above.  That said, I tried it both ways.

```
var jira = Jira.CreateRestClient(jiraUrl, "user@domain","apikey");
```

When that executes it throws the following exception:

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void RestSharp.RestClient..ctor(System.String)'.
   at Atlassian.Jira.Remote.JiraRestClient..ctor(String url, IAuthenticator authenticator, JiraRestClientSettings settings)
   at Atlassian.Jira.Remote.JiraRestClient..ctor(String url, String username, String password, JiraRestClientSettings settings)
   at Atlassian.Jira.Jira.CreateRestClient(String url, String username, String password, JiraRestClientSettings settings)
```

Using the exact same credentials with a RestSharp RestClient works fine.

```
var auth = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("user@domain", "apikey");
var jiraOptions = new RestClientOptions(jiraUrl) {Authenticator = auth };
var jira = new RestClient(jiraOptions);
```

### Versions

| Item | Version |
| --- | --- |
| .NET | Core 3.1 |
| Atlassian.SDK | 13.0.0 |
| RestSharp | 110.2.0 |
| Newtonsoft.Json | 13.0.3 (added this explicitly to see if it would help ... it did not). |

Comment: (I know this is months old but, for documentation sakes) From what I can infer, this error is caused by the Atlassian.SDK supporting RestSharp >= 106.12.0 but,  is doesn't actually support anything greater than 106.15.0. RestSharp v107 is where e.g. Method.GET changes to Method.Get. So this will be an issue until the maintainers of Atlassian.SDK update their code.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/farmas/atlassian.net-sdk/pull-requests/112

Answer (score 0):

Nicholas_Jones comment actually helped me. I was in 110.2.0 RestSharp with `, Method.Get);`. After I reinstall RestSharp 106.12.0 and change `Get` to `GET`.